# Regex Python Extract number

Tags: python, regex

how can I extract only numbers from text string.
Many times appear C{d}{d}{d}... which has to be removed. Only persist numbers.

```
text=['C1412DRE, New York 2695','Direction 12','Main Street 6254 C13D']
re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', '', str(text))


Desired output:
[2695,12,6254]
```

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\w)` or use a word boundary `\b\d+\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without regexp

```
text = ['C1412DRE, New York 2695','Direction 12','Main Street 6254 C13D']
str = ' '.join(text)
[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
[2695, 12, 6254]
```

with regexp:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
['2695', '12', '6254']
```

and convert them to digits

```
[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str)]
[2695, 12, 6254]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

The great playgroud where you may try your regexp with codegen: https://regex101.com/r/4kUHhq/1

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to strip away all alpha characters, I would rather search for all standalone numbers.  Here is one option, using `re.findall` with the regex pattern `\b\d+\b`:

```
text = ['C1412DRE, New York 2695','Direction 12','Main Street 6254 C13D']
inp = ' '.join(text)
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', inp)
print(matches)

['2695', '12', '6254']
```

One possible flaw in my logic is that I join together your list of strings into a single string, separated by space.  This is required because `re.findall` expects a single string for searching.  But, since the regex pattern is only looking for numbers already separated by a word boundary, joining by space should not introduce any side effects (I think).